# T-SQL DELETE statement. Only delete rows of certain criteria based on other row

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a simplified table of Cancer-examinations.:

```
Examination     Round           Corrected
-------------------------------------------
exam001         round001            0
exam002         round001            1
exam003         round002            0
exam004         round002            1
exam005         round003            0
exam006         round003            0
```

I want to write a query that removes `exam001` and `exam003`.

Lets look at `round001`. It has `exam001` and `exam002` connected to it.
But since `exam002` is corrected, we know that there was something wrong 
with `exam001`. Hence, I want to remove it. 
I do not want to delete any exams for round003, since none of them
are corrected.

So in pseudocode:

```
foreach round
delete all exams where corrected == 0
if round has exam where corrected == 1
```

It is given that every round has exactly 2 exams.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use EXISTS() for that matter .

Delete all corrected = 0 if a row exists for the same round with corrected 1

```
DELETE FROM Cancer-Examinations t
WHERE t.Corrected = 0
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 from Cancer-Examinations s where t.round = s.round and s.corrected = 1)
```